# How to break a nested list and obtain the items separated with a comma?

Tags: python, string, scipy, eval, nested-lists

I have a nested list called `model` and I want to use its items as the inputs of

```
scipy.stats.kruskal()
```

That is, if my nested list has n=5 lists inside it, I want to obtain

```
scipy.stats.kruskal(model[0],model[1],model[2],model[3],model[4])
```

However n changes depending on the application, and sometimes, instead of 5, I may have 3 and etc.

My initial idea was

```
    s=''
    for i in range(n):
        a='model_errors[{}],'.format(i)
        s+=a
    s=s[:-1]
    scipy.stats.kruskal(eval(s))
```

However eval() returns the initial nested list, and not the terms separated with a comma. I've been trying many different things, but none of them were successful.

Comment: `scipy.stats.kruskal(*model)` should do the trick. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3394898/129600

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `*`, it can pass a list to the function, and `**` for keyword arguments like dictionaries. So try `scipy.stats.kruskal(*model)`